# How to implement clickOutside Angular directive on ngFor Elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular7. I have a DOM of *ngFor Element.

My scenario is When I click/mouseover on any one element from that loop it will hide other elements and on mouse out it will show again.

My problem is when I click on any element its hiding other elements, but if I click on the outside of that DOM I need to show all elements.

I tried using click outside the directive of angular. but because of elements are in the loop , that function gets called multiple times.

Please, can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: please add the code that you have tried to your question

Comment: a working demo would be more helpful!